# Part inside of a faucet, bath to shower diverter

Tags: bathroom, shower, faucet, bathroom-fixtures

While taking off my old shower hose a part of my faucet came with it. Unfortunately this small plastic part got stuck to the hose and broke while I was taking it off. It originally had 4 raised tabs on the top part.

Does anyone know the name of this part?
[image: small part]

It’s the part that connects the shower hose to the faucet. It’s under the part that you pull up on to turn on the shower.

[image: where it connects]

If helpful I’m in Europe and would really like to be able to buy a new part instead of replacing the faucet.

Comment: Do you have a manufacturer for the faucet?

Comment: I think it's Hansgrohe

Comment: if it's a Hansgrohe you should be able to contact them for a spare part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being the part I needed: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00D849BZA/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

The part I originally sent a picture of is the bottom most part of the assembly linked above. Unfortunately that is not available individually but they do sell the part along with the section above that turns on the shower.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a "handheld shower fitting"?

I see a ridge around the part just under the remaining tabs. Is that what held it in place? If so, can you push it back up to snap in place?

For a more secure but permanent attachment you could use a bit of metal-safe silicone sealant around that ridge before popping it in place. In the US, one would take the part to a "plumbing supply house" where they should be able to source a replacement.  The faucet manufacturer may be able to supply one if you contact them, or you could cannibalize one from a new faucet.